# setting up laravel 5 artisan schedule:run on dokku (digitalocean)

Tags: cron, laravel-5, scheduler, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm having trouble setting up a cronjob for laravel 5 scheduler.

It seems like the `dokku run <app> <command>` command doesn't perform all commands inside the dokku container.

for example ... if I log into my server and I perform `dokku run <app> php artisan migrate --force` then it does migrate the DB.

But if try to perform a command like `dokku run <app> php artisan schedule:run` then I get the following response:

```
(touch /app/storage/framework/schedule-716d44b3c0c7f157011de8e9c5eca60e; /app/.heroku/php/bin/php artisan feed:import-last; rm /app/storage/framework/schedule-716d44b3c0c7f157011de8e9c5eca60e) > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But it doesn't process the the underlying actions.

The strange thing is that when I log into the dokku container with `dokku run <app> bash` and I run `php artisan schedule:run` then I get the same response, but then it does process the underlying actions.

This means that the cronjob `* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'dokku run admin-feedshop php artisan schedule:run'` won't do anything since it doesn't process the underlying actions this way.

Is there anyone who knows how I can get this thing working?

(I'm running dokku version 0.3.18)